# On integrating mahout with map reduce program, I get this error while parsing XML

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, bigdata, mahout

I get the below error when running the program. Any idea?

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/base/Charsets
            at org.apache.mahout.text.wikipedia.XmlInputFormat$XmlRecordReader.<init>(XmlInputFormat.java:76)
            at org.apache.mahout.text.wikipedia.XmlInputFormat.createRecordReader(XmlInputFormat.java:52)
            at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewTrackingRecordReader.<init>(MapTask.java:488)
            at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:731)
            at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:364)
            at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job$MapTaskRunnable.run(LocalJobRunner.java:223)
            at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
        Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.common.base.Charsets
            at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
            at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
            at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
            at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
            at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)*
```

Comment: an idea would be to post the code that throws this error.

Answer (score 0):

Class is not found under the package. Try to extract the jar file & traverse to com/google/common/base package. I think class is missing. Use another jar file which has **Charsets** class